# I'm having trouble creating some basic filtering using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My index page displays all images from my images table with the newest submissions on top. I'm trying to add some basic filtering so I can grasp the concept but I'm doing something wrong. My idea is:

Add 2 `<a>` elements with URLs to `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/ascending`. If the user goes to `www.domain.com`, the images will be displayed in descending order and if he goes to `www.domain.com/ascending` they will be displayed in ascending order.

Then I make my home route `Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');` have an optional parameter like `Route::get('/{filter?}', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');`

Based on the optional parameter, I'll send different `$images` variable to the view:

```
public function index($filter){    
    switch($filter) {
        case 'ascending'    : $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();break;
        default             : $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    }

    return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

As soon as I did this, I got 2 problems so far:

Firstly, when I go to `www.domain.com`, I get `"Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"`

Secondly, after adding the optional parameter to the route `Route::get('/{filter?}', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');` I get send to my index page even when I'm going to URLs like `http://example.com/admin` or `http://example.com/albums`.

I believe this happens because my code assumes that `/admin` and `/albums` are the optional parameter in my http://example.com url and not a separate url like it should be.

```
Route::get('/{filter?}', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/image/{id}', 'PagesController@specificImage')->name('specificImage');
Route::get('/tags', 'PagesController@tags')->name('tags');
```

So even if I go to the tags route, the index view will be displayed instead of the tags view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this
www.domain.com?orderby=asc

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');

public function index(Request $request){

  $images = array();

  $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', $request->get('orderBy') ?? 'desc')->get();

  return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to set `$order = $request->get('orderBy') ?? "desc";` and avoid the `if($order)` clause altogether? DRY principals and whatnot.

Comment: if you're right, I'll correct it at the moment I do not notice, thanks for the @TimLewis

Comment: Even though `$request->get('orderBy') ?? 'desc'` can be simplified to be: `$request->get('orderBy', 'desc') ` yet there's a fault in it because it only checks if the value of `orderBy` is null, it does not check if the value equals to 'desc'. Therefore, if I pass 'show' or any arbitrary value apart from 'asc' or 'desc' it will throw an error. This is why Mr @RicardoCastillo its good to explain what your code does and how it solves the OP's problem

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you set $images = array(); first?

Comment: @Bobimaru I like declare all my variable before to use only for that

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use get params in this case to avoid conflicting urls. So that request to `/`
should now be

`/?order=asc` or `/?order=desc`

and rather switch the get param `order` to know whether to show the page in descending or ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, using query parameter looks best for filtering in this situation instead of having two (or more) url endpoints.

However, if you want to stick with your implementation there are few things to do:

1. Declare your routes without leading slash, e.g:

   ```
     Route::get('{filter?}', 'PagesController@index')->name('home')
   ```

   Not so sure this does make any difference though, but something I personally watchout for (slashes everywhere)
2. Use optional path variable with restricted values, by using `where()` after the route declaration:

   ```
   Route::get('{filter?}', 'PagesController@index')->name('home')->where('filter', 'ascending|');
   ```

   It accepts ascending or nothing.
3. Pass a default parameter to your controller method:

   ```
   public function index($filter = null)
   {
       .....
   }
   ```

   Just in case nothing was passed. This is one of the important points to note with optional path variables.

Finally, you can avoid `if` statement totally, by using a Ternary operator before making the query:

```
public function index($filter = null){    
    $order = $filter === 'ascending' ? 'asc' : 'desc';

    $images = Image::orderBy('created_at', $order)->get();

    return view('home', ['images' => $images]);
}
```

Comment: Oh no, I don't really prefer my implementation over the query parameter and to be completely frank with you I didn't know I could use such thing as query parameter. I just wanna follow the best convention.

Comment: Its okay. Then other answers should be helpful for you then. Otherwise, just in case there comes a need to use path variables, then this answer is useful.